# Retrieving value in Drop Down populated by javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic, web

Hi I have a drop down field on a email web form that is populated by code behind (JavaScript). The drop down works well but when the form is submitted the value selected by the user is not retrieved and shown in the email, The other text box values are all picked up but not the drop down. I know this might be something to do with JavaScript being client side or something but not sure how to get around this. I'm using classic asp to send the form using 'Request.Form("dropdown")'

I know there must be a simple solution to this but my programming skills are limited

Thanks
R

Comment: post your code what you've tried so far

Comment: this is the onload event on my HTML page <body onload="initListGroup('chainedmenu', document.contactform.coursetype, document.contactform.course, document.contactform.coursedate, 'savestate')">

Comment: what is the name of your dropdown form and post your javascript code

Comment: theres too much code two whole jacascript files

Comment: If you don't show us the code , how should we pick your mistakes up. You must not post the whole but only related codes. anyway best of luck with your problem